# MPAndroidChart:Realtime Linechart Start from Right

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am using [real-time line chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/RealtimeLineChartActivity.java), where graph data is moving from right to left,
but the problem is graph is starting from Zero(0), because of that It looks like wrong data is coming, I want graph should start from the most right and start moving to the left

[image]

I have tried these but not working

```
 val leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft()
 leftAxis.setEnabled(false)
 leftAxis.setStartAtZero(false)
 **OR**
 leftAxis.mAxisMinimum(3f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following properties:

```
mChart?.xAxis?.spaceMin = 2.5f // As per you requiedment
mChart?.xAxis?.spaceMax = 0.1f // As per you requiedment
```